# Communication with MIFARE Plus SL3 (commands)

Tags: android, protocols, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to communicate with a MIFARE Plus card - I need to read / write. However, I can't find the documentation I need to do this. I understand that the command set is under NDA (or something), but my company has access to the documents - I just don't know which ones I need to request from them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case anybody provides a really technical and detailed answer (fingers crossed), I am doing this on Android

Edit: the tags are security level 3.

Comment: What commands are available to you? Do you have, for example, `SetCommPort`, `SetPortOpen`, `mfAuto`, etc?

Comment: Do you mean in Android? If so, there is only a transceive method which accepts and returns an array of bytes.

Comment: There is also a getSak() method and a getAtqa() method. The class I am using is here for reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.html

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I don't think I can help. I have been using the GNetPlus protocol which is at a higher level than this, or something completely different, it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how you use the MIFARE Plus card, you will either need to use the MIFARE Classic protocol (if MIFARE Plus is used in backwards-compatibility protocol mode) or MIFARE Plus commands on top of ISO/IEC 14443-4 (ISO-DEP). In the first case, there is an additional AES authentication facility, though I'm not sure what readers support this.

How to use either of those protocols depend on your reader device and API. From the comments to your post I would guess that you are using Android, so I'll give a short explanation on that.

For MIFARE Classic protocol (SL1): Assuming you have an Android device based on NXP chipset (Broadcom NFC chipsets do not support this), you will see a MifareClassic tag technology for your MIFARE Plus card. Using the methods of the MifareClassic tag technology object, you can authenticate, read and write using the legacy protocol.

For MIFARE Plus protocol (SL3), you should see an IsoDep tag technology for your MIFARE Plus card. Using the transceive method of the IsoDep object, you can exchange MIFARE Plus commands. You can find these commands in the MIFARE Plus data sheets (e.g. NXP document DS171233 and DS163734).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The tags are SL3. DS163734 seems to be about a program that ready built to read these tags, but I am working on Android so this doesn't apply (or am i reading the wrong parts?). And i can't seem to find the DS171233 document. Would you be able to point me to it?

Comment: No, both of them are IC data sheet (one for Plus S and one for Plus X).

Comment: Btw. both documents are available on docstore (if you have been authorized for those document categories).